# Method remove() of Iterator in LinkedList

Tags: java, collections, listiterator

Could someone explain me how this method works, via. this place `if (next == lastReturned)`. I do not understand in which case `next` can be equal `lastReturned`.

```
public void remove() {
        checkForComodification();
        if (lastReturned == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException();

        Node<E> lastNext = lastReturned.next;
        unlink(lastReturned);
        if (next == lastReturned)
            next = lastNext;
        else
            nextIndex--;
        lastReturned = null;
        expectedModCount++;
    }
```

Thank for answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lastReturned` can also be `next` if the iterator's `previous` method has just been used:

```
public E previous() {
    checkForComodification();
    if (!hasPrevious())
        throw new NoSuchElementException();

    lastReturned = next = (next == null) ? last : next.prev; // <=====
    nextIndex--;
    return lastReturned.item;
}
```

So in that case (`previous()` then `remove()`), it's important that `remove` set `next` to the next item *after* the one that was just removed, which is what that `if (next == lastRemoved)` is doing.